# Swift Combine - prefix publisher on array

Tags: swift, combine, split-apply-combine

I'm playing around with publishers in Swift/Combine, I have a function that fetches 100 records and returns them as an array.

As a test I want to return just the first two items, but it's not working as I expected it to, it always returns 100, my feeling is that it's because, the first item is an array of 100 items, if so, how do I split them out?

```
import UIKit
import Combine

struct Post : Decodable {
    let userId: Int
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let body: String
}

//let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")!
let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!

var subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

func fetch() -> AnyPublisher<[Post], Never> {
    return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .tryCompactMap{ (arg) -> [Post]? in
            let (data, _) = arg
            return try JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data)
    }
        //.print("here")
        .replaceError(with: [])
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

fetch()
    .prefix(2)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { (comp) in
        print("comp: \(comp)")
    }) { (res) in
        print("Res: \(res.count)")
}.store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Update, this seems to work, not sure on the syntax though:

```
fetch()
.flatMap { Publishers.Sequence(sequence: $0) }
.prefix(2)
.sink(receiveCompletion: { (comp) in
  print("comp: \(comp)")
}) { (res) in
  print("Res: \(res)")
}.store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Comment: Your use of `flatMap` is the correct solution. You should post it as an answer. (You are allowed to answer your own question.)

Comment: @robmayoff that is true, but the .flatMap still produce a lot of data. see my answer, how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` to take the full array and extract only what you need. Take a look at the following example:

```
[Array(0..<100)].publisher.map { array in
  return Array(array[..<2])
}.sink(receiveValue: { items in
  print(items)
})
```

This is a publisher that publishes an array with 100 values. I then use `array[..<2]` to create an `ArraySlice` that contains the first two items. This slice is then converted to `Array` so it's easier to use later.

The `items` argument received in `sink` is an array with just two items.

Answer (score 1):

```
.flatMap(maxPublishers: 2)
```

Could be a better approach for you depending on what you want to accomplish overall.